# Docker project is much slower

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

What I did was move the project to work with docker containers. The project is quite large and I ended up with about 12 containers.

And now at the moment there are 2 identical servers running Ubuntu 18.04.

1. On the first server, the project is deployed as usual: running Nginx, PHP7.2-fpm, MySQL5.7 and other services.
2. On the second server, a project was raised on docker

The crux of the problem is that when testing the speed of processing multiple requests on both servers, the server on the docker shows much worse performance.

Here is the project on the original server (Test with ApacheBench n100 c100):

```
Server Software:        nginx
Server Hostname:        test.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,2048,128
TLS Server Name:        test.com
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        119121 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.827 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      12038500 bytes
HTML transferred:       11912100 bytes
Requests per second:    54.74 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1826.828 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       18.268 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          6435.39 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      144  152   4.4    152     160
Processing:    50  899 469.8    938    1660
Waiting:       48  896 469.7    936    1658
Total:        203 1051 473.8   1090    1819

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1090
  66%   1330
  75%   1458
  80%   1550
  90%   1702
  95%   1770
  98%   1815
  99%   1819
 100%   1819 (longest request)
```

Here is a docker project (Test with ApacheBench n100 c100):

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.19.1
Server Hostname:        test-dev.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,2048,128
TLS Server Name:        test-dev.com

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        724822 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   12.573 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        99
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 99, Exceptions: 0)
Non-2xx responses:      100
Total transferred:      72592310 bytes
HTML transferred:       72476910 bytes
Requests per second:    7.95 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       12572.860 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       125.729 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          5638.41 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      135  140   3.4    140     146
Processing:  1351 8110 3454.4  10254   12421
Waiting:     1338 8066 3443.4  10211   12416
Total:       1486 8250 3457.5  10397   12566

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  10397
  66%  10789
  75%  11078
  80%  11260
  90%  11801
  95%  12334
  98%  12519
  99%  12566
 100%  12566 (longest request)
```

I have already reviewed a lot of manuals, articles and other things. Tried a lot of advice. Nothing helps.

1. Tinkering with nework in docker
2. Disabled debugger in php
3. Used different versions of docker-compose
4. Rules for configuring docker deamon

All actions resulted in a good enough speed for one user. But under load, docker is just awfully slow.

Here is the docker-compose.yml (PHP, Mysql, Nginx located in back section):

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  dump:

services:

  # ------------- Front --------------

  # project base ------------------------------------
  bb_base:
    build:
      context: ../front/project-base
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../front/project-base:/var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
  # project ui-kit ----------------------------------
  bb_ui-kit:
    build:
      context: ../front/project-ui-kit
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../front/project-ui-kit:/var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-base:/var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
    command: sh /var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}/entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - bb_base
  # project auth ----------------------------------
  bb_auth:
    build:
      context: ../front/project-auth
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../front/project-auth:/var/www/${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-base:/var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-ui-kit:/var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    command: sh /var/www/${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}/entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - bb_ui-kit
  # project crm ----------------------------------
  bb_crm:
    build:
      context: ../front/project-crm
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../front/project-crm:/var/www/${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-base:/var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-ui-kit:/var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    command: sh /var/www/${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}/entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - bb_ui-kit
  # project link ----------------------------------
  bb_link:
    build:
      context: ../front/project-link
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../front/project-link:/var/www/${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-base:/var/www/${BB_BASE_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-ui-kit:/var/www/${BB_UI_KIT_WORKDIR}
    command: sh /var/www/${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}/entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - bb_ui-kit

  # --------------- Back ----------------

  # PHP -----------------------------------------------
  bb_php:
    user: "${USER_ID}:1000"
    build:
      context: ../back/project-back/images/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - DOMAIN=${DOMAIN}
        - ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
    container_name: ${BB_PHP_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
#    ports:
#      - "${PORT_PHP}:9000"
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_PHP_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-back:/var/www/${BB_PHP_WORKDIR}
      #- photos:/var/www/${BB_PHP_WORKDIR}/storage/app/photos-mount
    depends_on:
      - bb_mysql
  # Nginx -----------------------------------------------
  bb_nginx:
    build:
      context: ../back/project-back/images/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - DOMAIN=${DOMAIN}
        - ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
        - BACK_DIR=${BB_PHP_WORKDIR}
        - LOCAL_DIR=${BB_NGINX_WORKDIR}
        - LINK_DIR=${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
        - AUTH_DIR=${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
        - CRM_DIR=${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
    container_name: ${BB_NGINX_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT_HTTP}:80"
      - "${PORT_HTTPS}:443"
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_NGINX_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-back:/var/www/${BB_NGINX_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-crm:/var/www/${BB_CRM_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-auth:/var/www/${BB_AUTH_WORKDIR}
      - ../front/project-link:/var/www/${BB_LINK_WORKDIR}
    depends_on:
      - bb_php
  # MySQL -------------------------------------------------
  bb_mysql:
    image: gitlab.project.ru:5050/project/backend/project/mysql:1.0
    container_name: ${BB_MYSQL_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${PORT_MYSQL}:3306"
    volumes:
      - dump:/var/lib/mysql
      - ../back/project-back/images/mysql/mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
      - ../back/project-back/images/mysql/mysqldump.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
      - ../back/project-back/images/mysql/optimize.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/optimize.cnf
    env_file:
      - ../back/project-back/.env
  # Redis -------------------------------------------------
  bb_redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine
    container_name: ${BB_REDIS_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
#    ports:
#      - "${PORT_REDIS}:6379"
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-back/images/redis/redis.conf:/redis.conf
    depends_on:
      - bb_php
      - bb_mysql
    command: [ "redis-server", "/redis.conf" ]
  # Mysql-cron-backup --------------------------------------
  bb_mysql_cron_backup:
    build:
      context: ../back/project-back/images/mysql-cron-backup
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${BB_MYSQL_CRON_BACKUP}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUME_PATH}/backup:/backup
    environment:
      - MAX_BACKUPS=${MAX_BACKUPS}
      - INIT_BACKUP=0
      - CRON_TIME=*/15 * * * *
      - GZIP_LEVEL=9
    depends_on:
      - bb_mysql
    env_file:
      - ../back/project-back/.env

  # --------------- Services -------------

  # Socket -----------------------------------------------
  bb_socket:
    build:
      context: ../back/project-services/project-sockets
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${BB_SOCKETS_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${BB_SOCKETS_WORKDIR}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-services/project-sockets:/var/www/${BB_SOCKETS_WORKDIR}
  # Recommend products ------------------------------------
  bb_recommend:
    image: prod_rec:latest
    build:
      context: ../back/project-services/project-recommendation
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${BB_RECCOMEND_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT_RP}:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=${FLASK_APP}
      - FLASK_DEBUG=${FLASK_DEBUG}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - DATABASE_URL_APP=${DATABASE_URL_APP}
      - DATABASE_URL_PROD=${DATABASE_URL_PROD}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-services/project-recommendation/config.py:/home/prod_rec/config.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-recommendation/app.py:/home/prod_rec/app.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-recommendation/app:/home/prod_rec/app
      - ../back/project-services/project-recommendation/migrations:/home/prod_rec/migrations
    depends_on:
      - bb_recommend_mysql
    links:
      - bb_recommend_mysql:dbserver
  # Recommend products MySQL ------------------------------------
  bb_recommend_mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    container_name: ${BB_RECCOMEND_MYSQL_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${RP_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${RP_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${RP_MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${RP_MYSQL_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-services/project-recommendation/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf:ro
  # Cdek ----------------------------------------------
  bb_cdek:
    image: cdek:latest
    build:
      context: ../back/project-services/project-cdek
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${BB_CDEK_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT_CDEK}:8080"
    env_file:
      - ../back/project-services/project-cdek/.env
    environment:
      - DEBUG_VALUE=FALSE
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-services/project-cdek/flask_api.py:/home/cdek/cdek/flask_api.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-cdek/boot.sh:/home/cdek/cdek/boot.sh
  # MoySklad -----------------------------------------------
  bb_moysklad:
    image: moysklad:latest
    build:
      context: ../back/project-services/project-moysklad
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${BB_MOYSKLAD_WORKDIR}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT_MOYSKLAD}:5000"
    environment:
      - QUART_APP=${QUART_APP}
      - QUART_DEBUG=${QUART_DEBUG}
      - SECRET_KEY=${MS_SECRET_KEY}
      - ENV=${MS_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ../back/project-services/project-moysklad/app.py:/home/moysklad/app.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-moysklad/webhook.log:/home/moysklad/webhook.log
      - ../back/project-services/project-moysklad/async_file.py:/home/moysklad/async_file.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-moysklad/config.py:/home/moysklad/config.py
      - ../back/project-services/project-moysklad/start.py:/home/moysklad/start.py
```

Well, that's the problem. How to solve the problem in speed with a high load on the project? Why is docker so slow under load? Any ideas?

If you need any more data, I'll attach it.

Comment: Which cloud provider are you using? Are you using a VPS managed by yourself?

Comment: Are your cgroup driver limiting the container resources? You can run `docker stats` to see runtime metrics, and if configured, resource limits. For a better monitoring, you can use [cAdvisor](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/cadvisor/) to gather Prometheus-friendly usage statistics from your Docker containers. Also, you may use Prometheus exporters for Nginx and MySQL to see their behavior when running in different environments.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use a hybrid setup where you've moved the PHP interpreter inside Docker's isolation layer, but are still trying to use your host code.  Does removing most of the `volumes:` help performance?  (There are similar questions especially about PHP performance on both MacOS and WSL.)